# 500 internal server on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, datatables

I am using server side processing for my datatables in MVC 2.0 hosted on a server using IIS 7.0. I have a controller which I am using to handle the incoming requests. When I view the page on my localhost , it works fine and this is a sample of the request header it sends

```
http://localhost:42417/EmissionByRegion/DataProviderAction?_=1337611318226&sEcho=1&iColumns=40&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&.......[it
 goes on till 39 columns]
```

This gets a valid json response and everything works well. But when I publish this code on a server which is using IIS  , when there is a postback to the server with the same request parameters.
In that case , I get the following Error

```
500 - Internal server error.
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Module IsapiFilterModule
Notification AuthenticateRequest
Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code 0x8007007a
```

What do I do to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is enable detailed error mode by adding the following to the system.webServer section of your web.config:

`<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />`

Comment: Mmm OK, I'm used to seeing more detailed information than that. You might consider renaming the title of your question "500 internal error" is far too broad. More specifically, it's about "Error Code 0x8007007a in Module IsapiFilterModule".